# Toggling Attribute Value Based On Page Id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

If I have markup

```
  <div data-role="page"  @(Page.Id == null ? string.Empty : "id=" + Page.Id) data-fullscreen="false">
```

In my _Layout page and when someone goes to my Browse.cshtml view I want to change 
data-fullscreen="true" how could I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean "someone goes to `Browse.cshtml` view"? Nobody can go directly to view in asp.net MVC, all interaction is going thru actions.

Comment: You could have a separate layout that you use for Browse. Otherwise, you need to take that div out of your layout and put it in a partial.

Comment: The jquery mobile template from visual studio does not have the layout referenced in the views but the views are picking it up. Any idea what in the template is letting the views pick up the default layout template. If I knew this I could create another layout for my Browse view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#div").attr("data-fullscreen", "true");
```